# Given $n=p_1^{k_1},...,p_r^{k_r}$. Show that $a^{lcm(\phi{(p_1^{k_1})},\phi{(p_2^{k_2})},...,\phi({p_r^{k_r})})}\equiv 1\pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

I am doing revision for my final exam. This is a sample question given by TA.

I actually have some idea, but wondering it is true or not.

I guess $lcm(\phi{(p_1^{k_1})},\phi{(p_2^{k_2})},...,\phi({p_r^{k_r})})$ here is just equal to $\phi{(n)}$, right? Then, it is just another form of Euler's Theorem.

Can anyone answer this for me?

Comment: That's essentially [Carmichael's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), except for when one of the primes is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

The $lcm$ is NOT equal to $\phi(n)$ -- just think of the case case when all of the $k$s are $1.$ However, note that $a^{lcm}$ is $1$ mod every one of $p_i^{k_i},$ (by Euler's theorem, as you say), and hence is equal to $1$ modulo $n$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: Thanks, i know how to do it now:)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case that $\text{lcm}(\phi(p_1^{k_1}), \ldots, \phi(p_r^{k_r}))$ is necessarily equal to $\phi(n)$:  Take $n=12$, for instance.  In order to prove your statement, try showing that the congruence holds modulo each of the prime powers $p_i^{k_i}$ using Euler's theorem for those numbers.